# First subplot (out of 2 with broken x axis) not being visualized

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot a time series with a break of about one year in the middle. I attempted to essentially make 2 subplots sharing a y-axis, with a break between two x limits. However, the first plot (the first period of the time series, before the break) doesn't show up. Any suggestions?

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\work\Documents\DavisData\graphs\2020')
for c in relevant_categories:
    if subset_m[c].sum() > 0:
        
#         plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
        f,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True, facecolor='w')
        ax = subset_m[c].plot(color='tomato', grid = False, label='Davis Topics')
        ax2 = subset_m[c].plot(color='tomato', grid = False, label='Davis Topics')
        
        ### make the break
        ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), datetime.date(2017, 12, 30)])
        ax2.set_xlim([datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), datetime.date(2020, 7, 1)])
        
        # hide the spines between ax and ax2
        ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.tick_left()
        ax.tick_params(labelright='off')
        ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
        
        plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, this is the graph I receive:

[image]

Comment: my guess is that the x-axis limits you've chosen are wrong. it's impossible to know though, since your example isn't runnable

Comment: oh -- you also aren't passing your axes objects to the `Series.plot` methods

Comment: essentially, I have a dataframe with a number of columns (ie. the 'Relevant Categories'), I run through each category and extract the column to plot.

Comment: how do i pass through a ```Series.plot```?

Comment: The `ax` parameter is described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html

Answer (score 3):

```
ax = subset_m[c].plot(color='tomato', grid = False, label='Davis Topics')
ax2 = subset_m[c].plot(color='tomato', grid = False, label='Davis Topics')
```

should be

```
subset_m[c].plot(color='tomato', grid = False, label='Davis Topics', ax=ax)
subset_m[c].plot(color='tomato', grid = False, label='Davis Topics', ax=ax2)
```